# Disable Table Triggers before adding a new column?

Tags: sql-server-2012, triggers

Does it matter if there are table (after Insert/Update) triggers that are active before I modify the table and add one or two columns or do I need to disable the triggers first, add the columns then enable them again?

Thanks

Comment: I tried both ways and it worked but I'm not sure if there might be some side effects in certain scenarios.

Comment: No, the trigger won't matter, as it can't have a dependency on columns which do not exist.